# Dynamic loading data in mailchimp API

Tags: php, expression, mailchimp

Mailchimp code:

```
$api = new MCAPI ('xxxxxxxxxxxx-us11')
```

This is my code:

```
$api = new MCAPI ('<?php echo $member[chimpapi]; ?>')
```

The second for the `listID`:

```
$api = new MCAPI ('<?php echo $member[chimplist]; ?>')
```

Of course this is not good not working, any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the your question to indent your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. I also removed the call for help in the end as it is not expected in SO. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Mailchimp API, but this piece of code:

```
$api = new MCAPI ('xxxxxxxxxxxx-us11');
```

is already PHP code, there is no need to include the php tags in it:

```
$api = new MCAPI ($member['chimpapi']);
```

and

```
$api = new MCAPI ($member['chimplist']);
```

Comment: yes, but I want dynamically load my members data (their api)